# Is there a sample code that integrates spring-security-saml2 with a no spring app?

Tags: spring-security, spring-saml

Im trying to create a SP using SAML2, I see there is a good spring security extension for SAML, however the project that I'm working on does not have spring and I need to implement a SSO.

Reading at the extension documentation, seems that it can be use to no-spring projects, do you guys know if there are any code samples showing how to integrate both?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

there's an excellent blog (http://blog.samlsecurity.com/) which deals with Java and OpenSAML which i've used as a resource for much of my IdP implementation to test SAML/Spring (when using for the ServiceProvider)